# How to change <p> tag text, without remove underline or italic format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this situation

```
"<p><strong><em><u>Allow Ship Partial</u></em></strong></p>"
```

I want to change the `<p>` text but if use `$('p').text('another text')` it will be remove the text format.

There is any way that I can do that without loose the format?

Comment: `$('p u').text('another text')` would work in this case, but have you considered using CSS for the formatting?

Comment: @devlincarnate a `p`  element is not a valid child of `strong`, `em` or `u`.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that I am using an external plugin that generate me the <p> like that, and I have to keep using it that way

Comment: Could you instead focus on the text instead of the structure around it? e.g. do a find/replace on "Allow Ship Partial" vs DOM traversal?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're replacing the content of p with *another text* which happens to be

```
<strong><em><u>Allow Ship Partial</u></em></strong></p>
```

So you're replacing even the format tags. You should instead use

```
$('p strong em u').text('another text')
```

or even better

```
 $('p>strong>em>u').text('another text')
```

Comment: While this works, I'd worry about structure consistency. Can OP guarantee it's always going to be `p strong em u`? Managing variations of this is not ideal.

Comment: this won't work because <p> is generated dynamically , so sometimes will be <p><u>Allow Ship Partial</u></p> only , or even <p>Allow Ship Partial</p>

Comment: Ok, I think you should have stated that in your question. :-) @chazsolo's answer is the way to go. As far as I know there is no way to create a selector if you don't know the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use CSS for the styling of the

tag

it would look something like this

```
p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the parent of `p` using `parentNode`, iterate over the child nodes and append them to the `parent`, and then delete the original node.

```
    while(c.hasChildNodes()) p.appendChild(c.firstChild);
    p.removeChild(c);
```

```js
let c = document.querySelector("p"), p = c.parentNode;

while(c.hasChildNodes()) p.appendChild(c.firstChild);
p.removeChild(c);
```

```html
<p><strong><em>Hi</em></strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers may tackle your problem if your structure is always guaranteed (which I don't believe it is), then you can instead iterate recursively over child nodes until you find a text node. Once you have that, replace the text inline.

```js
function findTextElement(element) {
  for (let i = 0, n = element.childNodes.length; i < n; i++) {
    const child = element.childNodes[i];
    
    if (child.nodeType !==3) {
      return findTextElement(child);
    }

    return child;
  }
}

const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

[].forEach.call(ps, (node, i) => {
  const textElement = findTextElement(node);
  textElement.parentNode.innerHTML = `New String ${i + 1} retains formatting`;
});
```

```html
<p><strong><em><u>Allow Ship Partial 1</u></em></strong></p>
<p><em><strong>Allow Ship Partial 2</strong></em></p>
<p><u>Allow Ship Partial 3</u></p>
<p>Allow Ship Partial 4</p>
```

**Note** this example is just a first pass; there are most likely edge cases you will need to check against (like whether or not a text node is found, etc.). I've also not used jQuery as most jQuery methods do not include text nodes. You may be able to refactor this using [jQuery.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) if you prefer that route, filtering out non-text nodes on each iteration.

Comment: this works fine, even before the for loop we can ask for something like this element.hasChildNodes(), like a base case, return the element and avoid parent Node.innerHTML later, only textElement.innerHTML